# How to express transformations of exponential functions, "stretches" and "compressions", in terms of "dilations"?

Tags: exponential-function, transformation

When referring to the transformations of exponential functions, how do you refer to vertical "stretches" and "compressions" in terms of "a dilation of $z$ from the y-axis or x-axis"?

From my understanding,

For any factor $a > 0$, the function $f(x) = ab^x$

- is stretched vertically by factor $a$ if $|a|>1$
- is compressed vertically by factor $a$ if $0<∣a∣<1$

e.g. if you have $2b^x$, the function is that of $b^x$ stretched vertically by factor $2$.

What would be the equivalent of this in dilation terms - e.g. (for the above example) the function has dilated FROM the $x$-axis by factor $2$? Is this correct? Are there any other ways to express this?

Comment: Do you mean, how would one transform a given function, so that the graph of that function is stretched (dilated if you prefer) across the x-axis?

Comment: @DavidKipper - yes, so would a vertical stretch equate to a dilation FROM x-axis, and a vertical compression equate to a dilation FROM y-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can understand what kind of action would correspond to what kind of transformation with respect to a given variable by isolating the variable we want to affect. However, everything I'll write is intuitive and non-formal.

Consider $y=f(x)$, and some $|a|>1.$ By looking at $y=af(x),$ we have increased the size of $y$ for any given $x$ - which corresponds to the graph of $f(x)$ stretching vertically. Easy stuff.

Now, had we wanted to translate or stretch $f(x)$ along the horizontal part of the graph, i.e. the domain, input, range of definition, etc. we'd like to do some action to the variable - "doing stuff" inside the function.

Let's look at $y=f(ax).$ For $|a|>1$, our graph would shrink along the $x$-axis - this happens, in an intuitive fashion, because we've increased the size of our input, and hence the function reaches any point of output earlier - which is to say more to the left, and again not at all formally, under $ax.$ Thus, multiplication of the input $x$ by $|a|>1$ would squish our function along the vertical axis, and multiplication by $|a|<1$ would correspond to a stretch of the function along the $x$ axis - imagine now the function ranges over smaller inputs and takes longer to reach a given output.

Finally, when it comes to taking the graph and translating it, the same lines of reasoning (what axis=variable do I want to affect and how <-> what is the variable associated with that axis and what is the action associated with my transformation) should make it quite clear what to do.

Hope this clarifies things.